# Linux Mint: using qt creator with qt4.6.3

Tags: linux, qt4

I have been trying to get my QT ide running to build some programs for FriendlyARM mini 2440.

I have cross compiled the Qt and tslib for my target by referring:-

https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/compiling-qt-and-tslib-for-mini2440-and-run-a-demo-app/

http://mini2440vietnam.blogspot.in/2011/04/upgrade-qt462-in-mini2440.html

Later-on, i installed Qt creator, and tried configuring it according to:-

http://mini2440vietnam.blogspot.in/2011/05/programming-application-for-mini2440-by.html

However, i am facing problems while adding **qmake** to the Qt creator.
I am getting the error: **"No compiler can produce code for this QT version. Please define one or more compilers".**

I have even installed MinGW, but the error still persists.

[image]

The compiler and debugger have been Auto-Detected, but this error comes when i give the path of qmake.

Similar questions have been asked before, but I am unable to find a source that explains what I should do. Apologies for that!!

Edit:- This is what i see in my terminal.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:-

Step 1-install qt-sdk, in mint(or ubuntu): sudo apt-get install qt-sdk.

Step 2-in Qt creator, select Tools->options->Build & Run->Qt Versions.

Step 3-click Add and browse to where qmake is located, on my device it was in /usr/share/qt4/bin/qmake. On other distributions(other than mint and ubuntu) browse to where it is located.

Step 4-now you have Qt, although you might see a warning sign on the version added.

Step 5-go to kits tab and select the qt version you added in any kit you want to add.

Regards,
Abhishek.